# Create instance of a python class , declared in python, with C API

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I want to create an instance of a Python class defined in the `__main__` scope with the C API.

For example, the class is called `MyClass` and is defined as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The class type lives under `__main__` scope.

Within the C application, I want to create an instance of this class. This could have been simply possible with `PyInstance_New` as it takes class name. However this function is not available in Python3.

Any help or suggestions for alternatives are appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the simplest approach is:

```
/* get sys.modules dict */
PyObject* sys_mod_dict = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
/* get the __main__ module object */
PyObject* main_mod = PyMapping_GetItemString(sys_mod_dict, "__main__");
/* call the class inside the __main__ module */
PyObject* instance = PyObject_CallMethod(main_mod, "MyClass", "");
```

plus of course error checking. You need only DECREF `instance` when you're done with it, the other two are borrowed references.