# How can I use PyObject_IsInstance with a non-builtin class as second argument?

Tags: python, c, instance, pyobject

In C/C++, I want to see if a `PyObject` is an instance. Unfortunately, the `PyInstance_Check` macro doesn't work with new-style classes.

So, according to forums posts that I read, `PyObject_IsInstance` could solve the problem. However, all the examples that I have found are demonstrating comparisons with built-in types, like ints and strings.

I want to know how I can construct a PyObject that represents a class of a type, so I can pass it to the second argument of `PyObject_IsInstance`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

I have finally found the answer myself, based on the contents of that page: [Create instance of a python class , declared in python, with C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147452/create-instance-of-a-python-class-declared-in-python-with-c-api)

```
// PyInstance_Check works only for old-style classes.
qBool isInstance = PyInstance_Check(pyInstance);
if (!isInstance)
{
    // It might be an instance of a new-style class.
    //
    PyRef module = PyImport_ImportModule("module.where.myclass.is");
    PyObject* moduleDict = PyModule_GetDict(module.Get());
    PyObject* protocolClass = PyDict_GetItemString(moduleDict, "MyClass");

    int returnValue = PyObject_IsInstance(pyObject, protocolClass);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply call `PyObject_GetAttrString()` instead of `PyModule_GetDict()` + `PyDict_GetItemString()` ?
Also, `PyRef` is not in the Python/C-API reference. Where did it came from?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the corresponding `PyTypeObject` if it is defined in the same module. If the type object (let's say it's called `ProtocolType`) is not visible from where you want to use `PyObject_IsInstance`, first declare a prototype with:

```
extern PyTypeObject ProtocolType;
```

And then use it like this:

```
PyObject_IsInstance(object, reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(&ProtocolType))
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is C++, and the question is tagged C. Use a C-style cast.