# How to access python class from C extension?

Tags: c, python-2.7, ffi, python-extensions

I have my extension for Python written in C. Currently I need to process in a function of my extension objects of a type declared in some external pure python module (Say, its name is `ext_module`). First of all I need to ensure that input object type corresponds some class from `ext_module`. How can I implement this?
Some additional code:

```
static PyObject * extensionFunction( PyObject* self, PyObject *args ) {
    const char *inputString = NULL;
    PyObject *inputList = NULL;

    if ( 0 == PyArg_ParseTuple( args, "sO", &inputString, &inputList ) ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ( 0 != PyList_Check( inputList ) ) {
    // here I need to check whether the list items are instances of ext_module.ExtClass
    } else {
        PyErr_SetString( PyExc_TypeError, "extensionFunction: expected list" );
        return NULL;
    }
    // process arguments

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Actually I can just try to call the expected methods and get an exception `NotImplementedError`, but I'm not sure if this is correct approach.

Comment: check out http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html and `PyObject_IsInstance` and `PyObject_TypeCheck`. I suspect one of those is your answer.

Comment: @Adam, I've considered that interface before asking the question, but I could not figure out how to obtain `PyTypeObject` instance of a class I want to check.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11869355/321772 has an example for how to get `PyObject*` for a new-style class. `PyObject_IsInstance` uses a `PyObject*`. Alternatively you can hack it by making a "SetClass" C function that you call from Python that passes the class object in.

Comment: @Adam, thanks! It seems to be exactly what I want.